# How to change the Host used in route generation for a twig template?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-routing

Ok so i have a controller with an action and 2 routes associated with it:

```
/**
 * @Route("/index/preview/", name="mybundle.preview_index")
 * @Route("/", name="mybundle.index")
 * @Template
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $preview = ($request->get('_route') === 'mybundle.preview_index');
    $host = $request->getHttpHost(); //domain.com
    if(!$preivew){
        $host = 'domain2.com';
    }
    return array(
        'preivew' => $preview,
        'host' => $host,
        'basePath' => $preview?'mybundle.preview_':'mybundle.',
    );
}
```

Then I want to generate a route inside the twig template depending on the host:

```
{{ path(basePath~'index') }}
//Then somehow pass the host to this so that i get the intended domain
```

If I was accessing this route using the preview route then i would get:

```
domain.com/index/preview/
```

But if i wasnt it would give me:

```
domain2.com/
```

**What I Have Tried**

- Setting the router context from within the controller, but that doesnt change routes generated in twig

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of using `path()` i have to use `url()` and set the host in the context of the router:

```
if(!$preview){
    $context = $this->get('router')->getContext();
    $context->setHost($host);
}
```

Then twig:

```
{{ url(basePath~'index') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Symfony 6 and the code above is not working anymore.

On a API subdomain (api.example.com) I wanted to generate URLs based on the website subdomain ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)).

The host can only be changed by setting a new complete context:

```
#[AsEventListener(event: 'kernel.request', method: 'onKernelRequest', priority: 0)]
final readonly class APIListener
{
    public function __construct(private RequestContextAwareInterface $router)
    {
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        // My website hostname is stored in an environment variable
        $appHost = $event->getRequest()->server->get('APP_HOST');

        // Get the current context and change the host
        $newContext = $this->router->getContext()->setHost($appHost);
        
        // Set the new context
        $this->router->setContext($newContext);
    }
}
```

**Note:** be careful with the priority, a priority too high will not take your changes into consideration (the listener must be loaded after loading the router)